# Hibernate "EntityNotFoundException" - no row with given identifier, even when data exists in Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic

> I am currently facing an issue related to Hibernate in our project. Please find the below exception when the code is deployed to weblogic 14c env, please find the environment information as well. Could you please share any thoughts on this issue?

1. App Server - Weblogic 14c
2. Spring version - 5.3.7
3. Hibernate version - 3.6.7.final

Weird thing is, the same code works fine with below configuration

1. App Server - Weblogic 11g
2. Spring version - 3.1.2.Release
3. Hibernate version - 3.6.7.final

Exception thrown is :No row with the given identifier exists:
**[com.a.b.c.d.StyleEngineVariantEntity#StyleEngineVariantIdEntity [styleEngineVariantId=36859683, versionId=24624]] javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.a.b.c.d.StyleEngineVariantEntity#StyleEngineVariantIdEntity [styleEngineVariantId=36859683, versionId=24624]]**   at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1197) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]  at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:255) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.6.7.Final.jar:3.6.7.Final]     at com.a.b.c.d.SVehicleSearchDAOImpl.getSVehicles(SVehicleSearchDAOImpl.java:94) ~[svehicle-core-0.0.88-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.88-SNAPSHOT]   at com.a.b.c.d.SVehicleSearchDAOImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7bc18254.invoke() ~[svehicle-core-0.0.88-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]   at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]

Comment: I'm afraid if you don't provide an example of our code, it would be very hard to help you. For example, would be nice if you post your RestAPI, Entity class, Repository, and Service (if you have one). That would help

Comment: And your table schema.